# Reject fractional values in int fields in a Spring Boot REST request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation, spring-mvc

Controller method:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/template")
ResponseEntity<Object> createtemplate(@Valid @RequestBody Template template) {
        return templateService.createCsvTemplate(template);
}
```

Object class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Template {  
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Please provide a valid ID, must be greater than 0")
    private int id;
}
```

POST input:

```json
{
    "id": 5.5
}
```

The application accepts this value, setting the value of `id` to 5.  How can I reject accepting such fractional values,
throwing an error when one is received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, jackson serializes decimal value as integer because `ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` flag is true by default. Set `ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` to false should fix your problem. And your need to handle throwing exception also.

```
ObjectMapper.configure(DESERIALIZATION_FEATURE.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT, false);
```

You can set configuration this way

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DESERIALIZATION_FEATURE.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT, false);
    return mapper;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me where should I handle throwing exception? Is it my setter class?

Comment: You can handle in your application Global ExceptionHandler using specific exception handler method annotated `@ExceptionHandler(Your exception class)`